# How to get the same Object instance in another HTML?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am giving `new Class()` in an **HTML**, however I need to get the result of this **SET** in **another HTML**, **how do I do this?**

**OBS: I'm using JAVASCRIPT OOP and ECMASCRIPT 6.**

**URIControler.js**

```
class URIControler {
    constructor(URN){
        this._URN = URN;
    }

    static get URN()     { return this._URN; }
}
```

**FIRST.HTML**

```
<button id="via-parque" onclick="window.location.replace('planta.html')">VIA PARQUE SHOPPING</button>
<button id="outro" onclick="window.location.replace('planta.html')">OUTRO SHOPPING</button>

<script src="js/scripts/lib/uri-controler.js"></script>

<script>
    new URIControler("testing");
</script>
```

**TWO.HTML**

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPT LIBRARY CONFIGURATIONS -->
<script src="js/scripts/lib/uri-controler.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts/lib/webstorage-controler.js"></script>

<script>
    console.log(URIControler.URN)
</script>
```

**RESULT:**

> **undefined**

Comment: This is not possible. Each HTML page is a separate program. The only way around this is to develop your website as a single page app

Comment: @slebetman, I am using OOP Javascript because I feel comfortable with the syntax of it, but the intention is to go through the SessionStorage, is it possible to join the OOP Javascript with the SessionStorage and get an information in the other HTML?

Comment: Yes. It's a similar trick to Hibernate in Java - serialize your object into a string (JSON is a good idea here) then store that string (sessionstorage, localstorage, cookies etc). Make the constructor able to accept an initializer object then in every page just do `new URIController(stateData)`